# Spring boot application is unable to connect to Debezium image of Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm currently stuck with a problem, that I can't connect to my kafka via Spring boot application. Kafka connector is working fine though and my changes are tracked.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
    networks:
      - kafka-network
  kafka:
    image: quay.io/debezium/kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    networks:
      - kafka-network
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:9092
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ~/kui/config.yml:/etc/kafkaui/dynamic_config.yaml
    networks:
      - kafka-network
    ...
  connect:
    image: quay.io/debezium/connect:latest
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    links:
      - kafka
      - mongo1
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
    networks:
      - my-mongo-cluster
      - kafka-network

networks:
  my-mongo-cluster:
  kafka-network:
```

My Spring boot application.properties is:

```yaml
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```

Error stack trace:

```
2023-06-12T21:47:18.196+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [           main] c.e.e.EmailServiceApplication            : Started EmailServiceApplication in 0.621 seconds (process running for 0.918)
2023-06-12T21:47:18.440+03:00  WARN 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {license_management.license-management.licenses=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2023-06-12T21:47:18.441+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Cluster ID: FnR8Yp18QamcXMJ3E5R8bQ
2023-06-12T21:47:18.446+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.96.3:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2023-06-12T21:47:18.447+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] (Re-)joining group
2023-06-12T21:47:27.923+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Disconnecting from node 2147483646 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9447 ms.
2023-06-12T21:47:27.924+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Group coordinator 192.168.96.3:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: null. isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.
2023-06-12T21:47:30.342+03:00  INFO 27186 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-email-service-1, groupId=email-service] Disconnecting from node 1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 11752 ms.
```

I tried to add environment variables to kafka configuration

```yaml
environment:
    - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=<Host IP>
    - ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<Host IP>:9092
```

but kafka didn't start.